# Tab autocompletion in bash using php

Tags: php, bash, autocomplete

I'm writing a simple script to autocomplete when I press TAB.

The php script contains a simple "echo".

In this case, the autocomplete works but a "tab" is appended to the output 
making it useless

Code from the script

```
scriptPath='/home/hassen/workspace/scripts/bin/test.php'

_dda()
{
    local cur
    COMPREPLY=()
    unset COMP_WORDS[0] #remove "j" from the array
    cur=${COMP_WORDS[*]}
    IFS=$'\n\n' read -d '' -a COMPREPLY < <($scriptPath --completion "$cur")
    return 0
}
complete -F _dda dda

alias dda=$scriptPath
```

Code from php script

```
<?php
echo "hello";
?>
```

Here is the annoying part:
If I print the echo in Python or Ruby, it works like a charm -- ie each time I press TAB, it calls the scripts and output hello.

Is this a bug with PHP or my code?
They seem to disagree  at http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52755

Comment: PHP doesn't seems fine to run in command-line. It has missing the #!/usr/bin/php5 part.

Comment: @fabrik Even if I had that, it doesn't help. 
I can call the script using ./test.php or php test.php -- both producing `hello`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as desired here, are you *very* sure the PHP file itself doesn't hold a tab, possibly after the `?>`?

Versions: PHP 5.3.2, GNU bash version 4.1.5

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I will try to upgrade. I'm running PHP 5.2.6

Thanks for testing

Answer (score 1):

CLIFramework provides a command helps you generate the bash completion script by your command definitions, so you don't have to write the completion script by hands:

https://github.com/c9s/CLIFramework

The screencast:

[image]

p.s. it also works for zsh

Answer (score 0):

There is a known problem in PHP that is documented here that prevents this from working.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53040

Use /usr/bin/**php-cgi** instead of /usr/bin/php for running the script and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, not directly with a custom bash completion, but through Makefile bash completion.

Workaround at [Makefile bash autocompletion issue with PHP generated targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233321/makefile-bash-autocompletion-issue-with-php-generated-targets)